# Java Inner class and capuring objects

Tags: java

The following code is an excerpt from Google's Guava library (`ThreadFactoryBuilder`) and is used to return a thread factory that names the threads using a user defined format string.

```
 private static ThreadFactory build(ThreadFactoryBuilder builder) {
 ...
 final AtomicLong count = (nameFormat != null) ? new AtomicLong(0) : null;
 return new ThreadFactory() {
    @Override public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
      Thread thread = backingThreadFactory.newThread(runnable);
      if (nameFormat != null) {
        thread.setName(format(nameFormat, count.getAndIncrement()));
      }
```

The question is, is there any advantage to the above code vs. moving the `AtomicLong` counter to the `ThreadFactory` class itself. I.e., the following code:

```
 private static ThreadFactory build(ThreadFactoryBuilder builder) {
 ...
  return new ThreadFactory() {
    final AtomicLong count = (nameFormat != null) ? new AtomicLong(0) : null;

    @Override public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
      Thread thread = backingThreadFactory.newThread(runnable);
      if (nameFormat != null) {
        thread.setName(format(nameFormat, count.getAndIncrement()));
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference, in practice.  The first code will be compiled to essentially the same thing as the second code, except it'll generate a synthetic constructor to store the `AtomicLong` reference in a synthetic local field.

The only difference is which gets instantiated first.  Other than that there is no difference.